# Emacs: How do I stop "*Buffer List*" from showing when opening 3+ files

Tags: emacs

When I open 3+ files in emacs, I get a split window with one of my files in the upper buffer and *Buffer List* in the lower buffer.

How can I get emacs to NOT put *Buffer List* there, but instead show another one of my files.

thanks.  -John

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html#index-inhibit_002dstartup_002dbuffer_002dmenu-4132).

*Note:* This option was introduced in Emacs 22.

For Emacs 21 and before, you could add the following workaround to your `.emacs` which will force Emacs to only have one window visible upon startup:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'delayed-delete-other-windows)
(defun delayed-delete-other-windows ()
  "need the call to happen after startup runs, so wait for idle"
  (run-with-idle-timer 0 nil 'delete-other-windows))
```

Comment: Thanks Trey.  This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.  Unfortunately it didn't work for me.  I added it to my .emacs and see the same behavoir when openning 3+ files.